# CPU overheating on a Sony Vaio VPCEA15FG

Tags: vaio, overheating

I have installed Ubuntu besides Windows7 on my laptop (Vaio Sony VPCEA15FG).
I can work with Windows for several hours without any problem; but as soon as I log into Ubuntu, my CPU overheats to 80C and turns off after less than 5 minutes.
Any idea how can I solve this problem?

Comment: Which Ubuntu do You use?

Comment: Are you using the default graphical drivers or Catalyst(fglrx)?

Comment: I have heard of many different Vaio models having heating issues.  After you check Sony's website and look for an updated BIOS, check [this Google Code](http://code.google.com/p/vaio-f11-linux/issues/list) page and see if you can find anything useful.

Answer (score 0):

have you considered jupiter?

also, when you run the system monitor, is your CPU percentage high?
(on some ubuntu versions I've had issues where things like software centre would use 100% cpu and my laptop would switch off in a few minutes)

Hope this helps!

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. This is really a **comment**, *not an answer* to the question. With sufficient [**reputation**](http://askubuntu.com/faq#reputation), you can use the "add comment" button to leave feedback for the author.